# Question about describing a sub-group of $S_{\mathbb{R}}$

Tags: group-theory, functions, normal-subgroups

We had the function $f(x)=x+1$.

What is $\langle f\rangle$ of $S_{\mathbb{R}}$?

How can I describe $\langle f\rangle$?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f^n(x)=x+n$, $f^{-1}(x)=x-1$, so $\langle f\rangle =\{x+n:n\in\Bbb Z\}$.

Comment: Great! Now I'm understand more about this subject!
Thank you!